# Java: ingresar en un vector un valor sabiendo su posición para mentener ordenado el vector

Tags: java, array, funciones, ordenamiento

llevo varias horas tratando de resolver una función buscar; a la cual le inserto un vector int, la cantidad de numeros introducidos y el numero que quiero buscar.

Es esta:

```java
    public static int buscar(int[] vec, int ins, int numero) {
        boolean encontrado=false;
        int bus=0, pos=0;   
            while(bus<ins&&!encontrado) {
                for(int i=0;i<ins;i++) {
                    if(numero==vec[i]) {
                        encontrado=true;
                        pos=i;
                    }
                    if (numero>vec[i])pos=i+1;                  

                    if (numero<vec[i]) pos=i;
                    bus++;
                }

            }
            if(encontrado)System.out.println("Está en la posición "+pos+"\n");
            else System.out.println("No está en ninguna posicion, deberia estar en la "+pos+"\n");
            return pos;
    }
```

Por defecto el vector[5] le doy un valor, 5 en el caso de prueba, al añadirle otro dato, llamo a esta función para que me diga la posición donde se colocará, 0 si es 4- o 1 si es 6+; esta parte bien la hace; en mi caso coloco 55, me da la posición 1 al ser más grande que el 5 y el vector se me queda como {5,55,0,0,0} pero ahora vienen los fallos, si quiero meter un valor inferior al 55 (en mi caso de prueba 4) me lo ordena así {5,4,55,0,0} cuando deberia darme la posición 0 para que pueda ordenarlo como {4,5,55,0,0}.

```java
import java.util.*;
public class EjClas {
    public static Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);

    public static void mostrar(int[]vec, int ins) {
        System.out.println("El vector es: ");
        for(int i=0;i<ins;i++) {
            System.out.print(vec[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void insertar(int[]vec, int ins) {
        System.out.println("Dime numero");
        if(ins==0) {
            vec[0]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        else {
            int aux;
            int num=sc.nextInt();
            int pos=buscar(vec,ins,num);
            for(int i=pos;i<ins+1;i++) {
                aux=vec[i];
                vec[i]=num;
                num=aux;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int buscar(int[] vec, int ins, int numero) {
        boolean encontrado=false;
        int bus=0, pos=0;   
            while(bus<2&&!encontrado) {
                for(int i=0;i<ins;i++) {
                    if(numero==vec[i]) {
                        encontrado=true;
                        pos=i;
                    }
                    if (numero>vec[i])pos=i+1;                  
                    System.out.println(vec[i]);
                    if (numero<vec[i]) pos=i-1;
                    bus++;
                }

            }
            if(encontrado)System.out.println("Está en la posición "+pos+"\n");
            else System.out.println("No está en ninguna posicion, deberia estar en la "+pos+"\n");
            return pos;
    }

    public static void eliminar(int[]vec, int ins) {
        System.out.println("Dime numero");
        if(ins==1) {
            vec[0]=0;
        }
        else {
            int aux;
            int num=sc.nextInt();
            int pos=buscar(vec,ins,num);
            for(int i=pos;i<ins+1;i++) {
                aux=vec[i+1];
                vec[i]=vec[i+1];
                num=aux;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        int vec[]=new int[5];
        int me1, ins=0;
        boolean sw1=false;
        while(!sw1) {
            System.out.println("Que quieres hacer");
            System.out.println("1. Insertar");
            System.out.println("2. Buscar");
            System.out.println("3. Eliminar");
            System.out.println("4. Mostrar");
            System.out.println("5. Salir");
            me1=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
            switch(me1) {

            case 1://insertar
                if(ins==vec.length) System.out.println("El vector está lleno, borra algo primero");
                else {
                    insertar(vec,ins);
                    ins++;
                    System.out.println();
                }
                break;

            case 2://buscar
                System.out.println("Que numero quieres buscar?");
                int num=sc.nextInt();
                buscar(vec, ins, num);
                break;

            case 3://eliminar
                if(ins==0)System.out.println("No hay nada que borrar");
                else {
                    eliminar(vec,ins);
                    ins--;
                }
                break;

            case 4://mostrar
                mostrar(vec, ins);
                break;

            case 5:
                sw1=true;
                break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Este es todo el codigo que tengo, agradeceria cualquier ayuda, que tengo la cabeza como un bombo ya de intentar cosas, si meterlo en un for, si sacarlo todo a un while y no logro nada.
Gracias.

Comment: Título != Descripción. El título es una idea general del contenido del mensaje. Revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla. Bienvenido/a a SOes :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Bueno he revisado tu código y he detectado lo que te sucede. te comparto el código con los ajustes realizados:*

*Tuve que ajustar los metodos buscar y eliminar

Cuando encontrabas que el numero ingresado es menor al que se está comparando, debías tomar la pocisión donde debe quedar el numero y finalizar el ciclo, porque si no lo finalizas los siguientes números van a ser mayores y a la final obtendrá la posición del ultimo numero comparado mayor al digitado y le dirá que tome la posición anterior quedando así almacenado como lo reflejas, también te pasa lo siguiente:

Supongamos que tienes agregado 2 datos en tu arreglo osea está asi: **[5,9,0,0,0]**, cuando ingresas un numero que sea mayor a 5 y menor a 9 es donde se complicaba dado que tenías 3 if:*

```js
if (numero == vec[i]) {
  encontrado = true;
  pos = i;
}
if (numero > vec[i]) pos = i + 1;
if (numero < vec[i]) pos = i - 1;
```

*Supongamos que vamos a agregar el 7, al hacer el recorrido en el ciclo, entraba primero al segundo if, diciendole que el numero 7 va a estar en la siguiente posición dado que 7 es mayor que 5, es decir en la posición 1; al comparar el siguiente entraría al ultimo if dado que 7 es menor que 9 y le estas diciendo que ocupe la posición anterior a la del nueve es decir i--, osea 1 - 1 = 0, al finalizar el ciclo el resultado sería la posición 0.
Teniendo en cuenta esto, he ajustado los condicionales en tu ciclo y lo he dejado de la siguiente manera:*

```js
if (numero == vec[i]) {
  encontrado = true;
  pos = i;
  break;
} else if (numero > vec[i]) {
  pos = i + 1;
} else if (numero < vec[i]) {
  pos = i;
  break;
}
```

*Haciendo así que cuando compare a 7 < 9 en ves de decirle que sea una posición menor, el 7 vaya a ocupar la posición de 9 para que en el ciclo donde ordenas los datos los números que sean mayores a 7 se muevan a la siguiente posición.*

**Para el caso de eliminar en el ciclo for tienes lo siguiente:**

```js
for (int i = pos; i < ins + 1; i++)
```

*estas aumentandole al tamaño de tu arreglo una posición y no estás ejecutando bien la el proceso para que mueva los datos dejandolos ordenados y con la ultima posición en cero, dado que es su valor inicial, para ello realicé el ajuste porque al sobre pasar el tamaño de tu arreglo e intentar agregarle información en una posición que no tiene entra a un exception. por tanto quedó de la siguiente manera:*

```js
for (int i = pos; i < ins; i++) {
  int nPos = i + 1;
  int nValor = 0;

  if (nPos >= ins) {
    nPos = i;
  } else {
    nValor = vec[nPos];
  }

  aux = nValor;
  vec[i] = nValor;
  num = aux;
}
```

**Comparto el código completo, como debería quedar:**

```js
import java.util.*;
public class EjClas {

    public static final Scanner SC = new Scanner (System.in);

    public static void mostrar(int[] vec, int ins) {
        System.out.println("El vector es: ");

        for(int i = 0; i < ins; i++) {
            System.out.print(vec[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void insertar(int[] vec, int ins) {
        System.out.println("Dime numero");

        if(ins == 0) {
            vec[0] = SC.nextInt();
        } else {
            int aux;
            int num = SC.nextInt();
            int pos = buscar(vec,ins,num);

            for(int i = pos; i < ins + 1; i++) {
                aux = vec[i];
                vec[i] = num;
                num = aux;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int buscar(int[] vec, int ins, int numero) {

        boolean encontrado = false;
        int pos = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < ins; i++) {
            System.out.println(vec[i]);

            if(numero == vec[i]) {
                encontrado = true;
                pos = i;
                break;
            }else if (numero > vec[i]) {
                pos = i + 1;
            } else if (numero < vec[i]) {
                pos = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(encontrado) {
            System.out.println("Está en la posición " + pos + "\n");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No está en ninguna posicion, deberia estar en la " + pos + "\n");
        }

        return pos;
    }

    public static void eliminar(int[] vec, int ins) {
        System.out.println("Dime numero");

        if(ins == 1) {
            vec[0] = 0;
        } else {
            int aux;
            int num = SC.nextInt();
            int pos = buscar(vec,ins,num);

            for(int i = pos; i < ins; i++) {
                int nPos = i + 1;
                int nValor = 0;

                if (nPos >= ins) {
                    nPos = i;
                } else {
                    nValor = vec[nPos];
                }

                aux = nValor;
                vec[i] = nValor;
                num = aux;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        int[] vec = new int[5];
        int me1;
        int ins = 0;
        boolean sw1 = false;

        while(!sw1) {
            System.out.println("Que quieres hacer");
            System.out.println("1. Insertar");
            System.out.println("2. Buscar");
            System.out.println("3. Eliminar");
            System.out.println("4. Mostrar");
            System.out.println("5. Salir");
            me1 = SC.nextInt();

            System.out.println();

            switch(me1) {

            case 1://insertar
                if(ins == vec.length) System.out.println("El vector está lleno, borra algo primero");
                else {
                    insertar(vec,ins);
                    ins++;
                    System.out.println();
                }
                break;

            case 2://buscar
                System.out.println("Que numero quieres buscar?");
                int num = SC.nextInt();
                buscar(vec, ins, num);
                break;

            case 3://eliminar
                if(ins == 0)System.out.println("No hay nada que borrar");
                else {
                    eliminar(vec,ins);
                    ins--;
                }
                break;

            case 4://mostrar
                mostrar(vec, ins);
                break;

            case 5:
                sw1 = true;
                break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Espero haber sido claro en lo que te he explicado.

Comment: Gracias por la resupesta, mejor explicado imposible, como no habia acabado con el buscar() no vi que tambien habia fallo en eliminar me has hecho un 2x1.